# html form validation (with jquery.validate.js) in some cases doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I want to create a html form that has to be filled with email address, some text and agreement in terms and conditions. When all 3 fields are valid, then the submit button should be enabled. So far I created the script and almost everything works fine. The html code is simple:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="email" name="email" class="textox" placeholder="your@email.com" />
    <br/>
    <textarea maxlength="140" style="resize:none" class="textoxarea" placeholder="zbzbzxcbcx" name="field2"></textarea>
    <br>

        <input type="checkbox" class="required" value="None" name="check">
        I accept terms</input>
    <input type="submit" disabled />
</form>
```

and the js code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            terms: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 2
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
    $('#myform').find('input, textarea').on('change', function () {
        var btn = $('#myform').find('input[type=submit]');
        if ($('#myform').valid()) {
            btn.removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });



});
```

The case that does not work in this example is: at the beginning the submit button is disabled. When user inputs the email address and checks the terms and conditions, the button is still disabled, because the user didn't fill the text area yet. When he fills it with more than 5 characters, the button should change to enabled. But it doesn't. It changes only when user clicks somewhere else on the page first - then the button changes its condition. But without clicking away - it's still disabled - how can I fix it?
My jsfiddle code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/263/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `change` event is fired for input HTML controls after they lose focus. More information about `change` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change. To react to any change before a control loses focus you need to listen to `input` event on all the text input controls in your form: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input. Watch out for IE - this only works 9+. To react to a change in the checkbox you should still use `change` event.

An alternative for text controls is a more dirty solution using combination of `keyup` and `paste` events.

**UPDATE**

In the above case I think the cleanest way is to:

1. Wrap the anonymous function into a named one e.g. `updateButtonState`
2. Bind checkbox using `change`
3. Bind text controls using `input`

   ```
   $('#myform').find('input:text, textarea').on('input', updateButtonState);
   $('#myform').find(':checkbox').on('change', updateButtonState);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, could you give me some example of that dirty hack with keyup and paste? And why exactly it's dirty? :)

Comment: Yes - you could just code it like this: $('#myform').find('input, textarea').on('change keyup paste', function () { .... }); It is dirty, because `keyup` actually will fire for any key you press when the control has focus (arrows, ESC etc.). In your case this will work, but I think better is to bind to `input` and `change`: $('#myform').find('input, textarea').on('input change', function () { .... });

Answer (score 0):

This can be quick fix but it will works....Add one more event keyup.

Change your code with below one.

```
$('#myform').find('input, textarea').on('change keyup', function () {
```

This may help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `'change'` use `'keyup paste'` as events. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/265/).